# Sometimes some users are not receving push notification through FCM

Tags: android, python, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When we try to send push notifications to users using FCM, most of the devices are getting the push, but few of the user devices sometimes receives the message, sometimes not.I am using php curl call to poll the device token in the set of 1000 devices.Please find the snippet below:

```
$icons="";
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIuasdasjkdjadkajsdkad999asdI");
define("GOOGLE_GCM_URL", "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
$fields = array(

'to'                        => $tokenArr ,
'priority'                  => "high",
'notification'              => array("body" =>     
$message,"icon"=>$icons),
'data'                      => array("message" =>$message),
);

$headers = array(
GOOGLE_GCM_URL,
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY 
);

echo "<br>";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
```

What could be the reason?
 Please give your valuable feedback on this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. It's hard to provide any kind of feedback with just the info you provided. Please provide a more detailed scenario, details where it happens, and relevant code snippets.

Comment: Hi. Do *edit* your post with the additional details instead of adding it in the comments section. :)

Comment: Note that the state of the network between FCM and the device can affect whether or not the device receives the message. Could you add the response from FCM when you send the request. Devices that are not connected to FCM would also not receive the message till they connect again.